# login page using multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, methods, boolean-expression

> i had try different way to check if input from the user is in my array.
>
> > it seems that is not that simple but i do not understand the exemples.
> >
> > > should i create another array to prompt user input and then compare them.

```js
var userName = prompt("What is your user name?");
var passWord = prompt("Enter your passWord");

// my array

var personInfo = [
  ["arelys", "are12", 1234],
  ["jamy", "jamy23", 4567],
  ["erika", "eri06", 1010]
];

for (var row = 0; row < personInfo.length; row++) {

  for (var col = 0; col < personInfo.length; col++) {
    personInfo[row][col];
  }

  // if (userName == personInfo[row].length && userName == personInfo[col].length) 

  if (userName == personInfo[row][col] && passWord == personInfo[row][col]) {
    document.write("found")

  } else {
    document.write("not found")
  }
  //document.write("<br />")
}
```

Comment: I formatted your code so it is cleaner. There is no reason you should have the second loop. You should be looking for personInfo[row][1] and personInfo[row][2] since you know the user name is in index 1 and password is in 2.

Comment: hello so something like this for(row = 0; row < personInfo.length; row++){if (userName == personInfo[row][1]) && password == personInfo[row][2]} just 1 for loop right. i try this way but with the two for loop. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work. 0 and 1 index will be considered as username and index 2 considered as password.

```js
var userName = prompt("What is your user name?");
var passWord = prompt("Enter your passWord");

// my array

var personInfo = [
  ["arelys", "are12", 1234],
  ["jamy", "jamy23", 4567],
  ["erika", "eri06", 1010]
];
var status = 0;
for (var row = 0; row < personInfo.length; row++) {
  // if (userName == personInfo[row].length && userName == personInfo[col].length) 
if(status !=1){
  if ((userName == personInfo[row][1] && passWord == personInfo[row][2]) || (userName == personInfo[row][0] && passWord == personInfo[row][2])) {
    document.write("found")
 status = 1;
  }
  }
  //document.write("<br />")
}
if(status == 0){
    document.write("not found")
}
```